# Do you know java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64.dll error in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring-webflux, netty

everyone

When I try the code below,

```java
private void request() {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
        .resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE)
        .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
        .doOnConnected(connection ->
            connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();

    String requestUrl = "https://my-url";
    Mono<String> result = webClient.post()
        .uri(requestUrl)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class);
        
    String token = result.block();
    return token;
}
```

This error occurred.. What should I do?

[image]

Thank you for share your knowledge.

Comment: I suppose, that your spring-webflux just attemp to find the best OS notification wrapper (e.g. epoll/kqueue/poll/select and (probably) IOCP for windows). Once it has resolved the best suitable option it stops producing the errors. So, if everything is working okay just ignore this. And if not, then there is some troubles with dependencies.